# ngx-translate: How to translate dynamically array of strings

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I want to create list of days of the week with ngx-translate, but it's not working with async pipe. I've got error "error TS2769: No overload matches this call." I have to use JSON file.

TS:

```
    MON:Observable<string> = this.translate.get('CALENDAR.MON');
      TUE:Observable<string> = this.translate.get('CALENDAR.TUE');
      WED:Observable<string> = this.translate.get('CALENDAR.WED');
      THU:Observable<string> = this.translate.get('CALENDAR.THU');
      FRI:Observable<string> = this.translate.get('CALENDAR.FRI');
      SAT:Observable<string> = this.translate.get('CALENDAR.SAT');
      SUN:Observable<string> = this.translate.get('CALENDAR.SUN');
    
    
    
      daysOfWeeks:string[] = [`${this.MON}`, `${this.TUE}`, `${this.WED}`, `${this.THU}`, `${this.FRI}`, `${this.SAT}`, `${this.SUN}`];

 constructor(
      public translate: TranslateService
    ) { }
```

HTML:

```
 <div *ngFor="let day of daysOfWeeks">{{ day | async}}</div>
```

I also tried use pipe directly into ngFor but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to share two ways of solving this problem.

1- you can use [translateService.instant](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core)

> instant(key: string|Array, interpolateParams?: Object):
> string|Object: Gets the instant translated value of a key (or an array
> of keys). /!\ This method is synchronous and the default file loader
> is asynchronous. You are responsible for knowing when your
> translations have been loaded and it is safe to use this method. If
> you are not sure then you should use the get method instead.

like this

```
//for single
    const traslateSingle :string =  this.translateService.instant("Monday"); // translated "Monday"

//for list
    const transaletedList = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"].map(x=> this.translateService.instant(x)) // translated Week days
```

But it has its own issues
what if translation has not been loaded ?
what if language selection has changed, now its ur responsibility to get updated translations

2- use [translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#5-use-the-service-the-pipe-or-the-directive) pipe in `component.html`

```
const daysOfWeeks = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"]
 <div *ngFor="let day of daysOfWeeks">{{ day | translate}}</div>
```

it take the responsibility and automatically translate text and detection language change and then translating again.

so its kind a better solution for your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to import strings from JSON file in i18n folder

Comment: yes its translate pipe is using it under the hood.
translateService is also using it. https://github.com/ngx-translate/core

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR

There is also a possibility to use indexed reference. Consider that you have 2 different language as English and Turkish;

*en.json*

```json
{
  ...
  "months": ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
}
```

*tr.json*

```json
{
  ...
  "months": ["Ocak", "Şubat", "Mart", "Nisan", "Mayıs", "Haziran", "Temmuz", "Ağustos", "Eylül", "Ekim", "Kasım", "Aralık"]
}
```

apply through those array definitions over translate instant output:

```js
getMonths(months: string[]): string[] {
    return months.map((_, i) => this.translateService.instant(`months.${i}`));
}
```

finally, it gives the result of new array which is translated for every item of it by calling the method, getMonths